# Simple recursive function to find parent object in nested data not finding parents?

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested

I have a nested data structure, and I want to create a recursive function that, given an object's name parameter, will return the parent object's name paramter.

There are several related questions, however, the answers don't explain why my function `getParentName` isn't working.

Why is `getParentName` not working?

```js
const nestedData = {
  name: "parent",
  children: [{ name: "child", children: [{ name: "grandchild" }] }],
};

function getParentName(nested, name) {
  if (nested.children && nested.children.map((d) => d.name).includes(name)) {
    return nested.name;
  } else if (nested.children) {
    nested.children.forEach((child) => {
      return getParentName(child, name);
    });
  }
  return undefined; //if not found
}

//The parent of "grandchild" is "child" - but the function returns undefined
const parentName = getParentName(nestedData, "grandchild");
```

Why does this function not find the parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your answer is `.forEach` ignores the `return` value. There is no `return` for your `else if` branch. `.forEach` is for side effects only. Consider using a generator which makes it easier to express your solution -

```js
function* getParentName({ name, children = [] }, query) {
  for (const child of children)
    if (child.name === query)
      yield name
    else
      yield *getParentName(child, query)
}

const data = {
  name: "parent",
  children: [{ name: "child", children: [{ name: "grandchild" }] }],
}

const [result1] = getParentName(data, "grandchild")
const [result2] = getParentName(data, "foobar")
const [result3] = getParentName(data, "parent")

console.log("result1", result1)
console.log("result2", result2)
console.log("result3", result3)
```

The answer will be `undefined` if no matching node is found or if a matched node does not have a parent -

```
result1 child
result2 undefined
result3 undefined
```

Notice `[]` is needed to capture a single result. This is because generators can return 1 or more values. If you do not like this syntax, you can write a generic `first` function which gets only the first value out of generator -

```js
function first(it) {
  for (const v of it)
    return v
}
```

```js
const result1 = first(getParentName(data, "grandchild"))
const result2 = first(getParentName(data, "foobar"))
const result3 = first(getParentName(data, "parent"))
```

The advantages of this approach are numerous. Your attempt uses `.map` and `.includes` both of which iterate through `children` completely. In the other branch, `.forEach` is used which exhaustively iterates through all `children` as well. This approach avoids unnecessary `.map` and `.includes` but also stops *immediately* after the first value is read.

Comment: Wow. I knew Array.forEach() method doesn't return a value, but I did not know it would ignore deliberate internal return statements. Typescript should complain about returning within forEach :/

Comment: the `return` you wrote belongs to an ordinary function used as a “callback.” this only signals to `.forEach` to move on to the next element. there may be a way to enable stricter TS behaviour to warn when void functions return a value. another option would be to abandon TS in favor of a superior (sound) type system like ReScript.

Answer (score 0):

@Mulan answered my question, stating that the function failed because return statements inside .forEach() are ignored. They then offered a generator function as a superior alternative.

For the sake of clarity of comparison, here is a minimally altered form of the original function that works. forEach() was replaced with a (for x of array) loop. In addition only truthy values are returned.

```js
function getParentName(nested, name) {
  if (nested.children && nested.children.some((d) => d.name === id)) {
    return nested.name;
  } else if (nested.children) {
    for (const child of node.children) {
      const result = getParentName(child, id);
      if (result) return result;
    }
  }
  return undefined; //if not found
}
```

Comment: Very nice exercise to take, good work. A couple things I would point out: 1) `nested.children.some(d => d.name === name)` is another way of writing `nested.children.map(d => d.name).includes(name)` that only iterates through `nested.children` once. 2) `for (var i = 0; ...) { return ... }` will immediately return the first `getParentName(...)`, and `i` will never increment to the second, third item and so so on. 3) `for (const d of children) { ... }` is a way you can avoid writing `for` loops that require fragile `i`-based incrementing and indexing.

Comment: to fix the premature `return`, you can write `for (...) { const result = getParentName(...); if (result) return result; }` this will only cause the function to return if `getParentName` returns an actual value, otherwise `for` will continue iterating :D

Comment: I will update my answer with your suggestions.